# update_attribute not doing anything after first_or_create if record does not exist previously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

I do a `first_or_create` statement, followed by a `update_attributes`:

```
hangout = Hangout.where(tour: tour, guide: current_user).first_or_create
hangout.update_attributes(priority: current_user.priority)
```

If the record already existed, it updates the priority. If it doesn't exist previously, there is no update. Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`update_attributes` (aka `update`) returns a boolean indicating if there was an error, if you do not check it - use bang-version `update!` so that exception will not be ignored.

Most probably record does not get created due to validation. Also when you're updating new record just after create - better use `first_or_create(priority: current_user.priority)` or `first_or_initialize`(with subsequent update) to spare extra DB write.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def update_attributes!(attributes)
    self.attributes = attributes
    save!
  end
```

update attribute with bang call the save with bang.

```
def save!(*args, &block)
  create_or_update(*args, &block) || raise(RecordNotSaved.new("Failed to save the record", self))
end
```

Inside the save! **RecordNotSave** error will be raise if it cannot save the record.

so you can customize the error handing from your code.

```
begin
    hangout.update_attributes!(priority: current_user.priority)
rescue RecordNotSaved => e
    #do the exception handling here
end
```